# How to add link with icon to wordpress admin bar?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I know that to add a link with an icon to the admin bar of wordpress (black bar at the top when you are loged in) you must register an action:

```
function add_toolbar_items($admin_bar){

    $admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id'    => 'my-id',
        'href'  => 'my-link',
        'title' => '<span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">Mudar número</span>',
    ));

}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_toolbar_items');
```

);

And there is this css that adds the icon to the link:

```
#wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-my-id .ab-icon:before {
    content: "\f525";
    top: 4px;
}
```

This solves my problem. But when I see the wordpress blog from a smaller screen (i.e. mobile) that icon just desapears. For some reason some wordpress css removes the icon that I've put in the side of the link's text.

So, how can I make the icon show in mobile devices?

Comment: by adding media query to your css

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#editor-underline